# Running local unit test(Junit and Mockito) in AOSP

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-source, android.mk

I created an application in android studio and written local unit test cases using Junit and Mockito.
These local unit test cases are pure Java test cases so device not needed for execution.

I run local unit test for my application in  android studio successfully.

Now I am trying to build the same application in AOSP as a system application.
I want to run the local unit test for the application in AOSP.

---

Project structure(AOSP):

Packages/apps/MYAPP/src                   ---> main java files

Packages/apps/MYAPP/res                   --->  resource files

Packages/apps/MYAPP/test                  ---> test java files

Packages/apps/MYAPP/Android.mk            ---> make file

Packages/apps/MYAPP/AndroidManifest.xml   ---> manifest file

---

If anyone have idea about executing  local unit test cases in AOSP please share.

Thanks in advance.